# Почему после слова "года" стоит запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В детстве, когда мне было три года, я начала заниматься лепкой.

Answer (score 4):

В детстве, **когда мне было три года**, я начала заниматься лепкой.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным времени, которое находится внутри главного предложения.

Придаточное имеет **уточняющую функцию**, так как стоит после уточняемого обстоятельства времени ***в детстве***.

Answer (score 1):

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором придаточное времени ("когда мне было три года") выделяется запятыми. "Когда" — это подчинительный союз.

***В детстве,*** (когда?) ***когда мне было три года,*** я начала заниматься лепкой.

[Придаточные времени](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/745-233_pridatochnye_vremeni.html)

В детстве, когда мне было шесть лет, я поджёг соседский сарай с сеном.
В детстве, когда они с родителями выезжали за город, она могла часами любоваться звёздами, щедро усеявшими небосклон...